How to figure out if Simpson's paradox in FE performance where errors go down, latency goes up
As per the question, our latency when I look at pages one on one seems about the same as before, sort of not great - barely passable.
But after a recent release our error rate dropped to about a 5th of the previous errors.
And our latency over all users shot up to be a bit more than double. Also a lot of other performance stats worsened.
We can't see anything that would be affecting the performance.
So I was thinking it might be that all a lot of those people who errored out early are now sticking around, but with bad performance, but I don't have any problems on individual analysis.
How can I start to figure this out?
I don't think this is just a redo of how to solve simpson's paradox question, since I am very uneducated in this it's more like identifying the confounding variable when users have errored out and now we have less errors, how to figure out what are the people who would have errored out before given these assumptions?
Hope this is understandable.

so why I think paradox - trend is reasonable performance in erroring out users (because error out early), reasonable performance in not erroring out, fix errors thus combining two groups - bad performance. But maybe that does not count as Paradox because there is some other term for this, some other way to describe it
